# itertools product should not contain combination having duplicate values

Tags: python, list, combinations

I am trying to create combinations. Sample code is as follow:

```
a = [1, 2, 3], [1, 4, 5]
combinations = list(itertools.product(*a))
```

Output:

```
[(1, 1), (1, 4), (1, 5), (2, 1), (2, 4), (2, 5), (3, 1), (3, 4), (3, 5)]
```

I don't need combination `(1,1)`. 
I have already tried following code:

```
for comb in combinations:
    if comb[0] == comb[1]:
        combinations.remove(comb)
```

But as I have to execute this on a large data. It's taking too much time.

Also the elements in combination should be equal to the number of items in the list.
For example: `a = [1,2,3], [2,3,7],[4,5,1]`
the elements in each combination would be 3, like `(1,2,4)`

Please suggest a way to avoid such combinations.

Comment: Would you only want to avoid `(1, 1, 1)` or also `(1, 1, 2)` and `(1, 2, 1)`?

Comment: @poke: Need to consider only combinations with unique values. So (1,1,2) & (1,2,1) should be discarded.

Answer (score 7):

For two iterables a simple list comprehension would do:

```
>>> from itertools import product
>>> a = [1, 2, 3], [1, 4, 5]
>>> [(x, y) for x, y in product(*a) if x != y]
[(1, 4), (1, 5), (2, 1), (2, 4), (2, 5), (3, 1), (3, 4), (3, 5)]
```

If you need to filter a product of **arbitrary** number of iterables, then it's better to use sets to check that all elements of a combination are distinct:

```
>>> a = [1, 2, 3], [1, 4, 5], [1, 8, 9]
>>> [p for p in product(*a) if len(set(p)) == len(p)]
[(1, 4, 8), (1, 4, 9), (1, 5, 8), (1, 5, 9), (2, 1, 8), (2, 1, 9), (2, 4, 1), (2, 4, 8), (2, 4, 9), (2, 5, 1), (2, 5, 8), (2, 5, 9), (3, 1, 8), (3, 1, 9), (3, 4, 1), (3, 4, 8), (3, 4, 9), (3, 5, 1), (3, 5, 8), (3, 5, 9)]
```

BTW, never alter the list you're looping on, because that's quite likely to produce an incorrect loop.

Comment: Thanks. However this logic would work if there are only two items (lists). In my case these items can be multiple. For eg. [1,2,3],[3,4,1],[4,31] and so on.

Comment: @panr...Is your requirements to get the 2 values product?..or what is the size of the product it?..you should've included this information in your question

Answer (score 4):

In case your list of lists can have more than two sublists, you could compare the size of the tuple to the size of the tuple after converting it to a `set`, thus filtering duplicate elements.

```
>>> import itertools
>>> b = [1,2,3],[1,4,5],[1,2,6]
>>> [x for x in itertools.product(*b) if len(x) == len(set(x))]
[(1, 4, 2), (1, 4, 6), (1, 5, 2), (1, 5, 6), 
 (2, 1, 6), (2, 4, 1), (2, 4, 6), (2, 5, 1), (2, 5, 6), 
 (3, 1, 2), (3, 1, 6), (3, 4, 1), (3, 4, 2), (3, 4, 6), (3, 5, 1), (3, 5, 2), (3, 5, 6)]
```

---

> It works fine but takes too long when the number of lists are more than 20. [...] Max count of lists would be 40 & items in each list can go up to 20.

Those are awfully many and awfully large lists. Even for 20 lists with 3 elements each you would have to go through 3^20 = 3,486,784,401 combinations. This can still be feasible, but you should use a generator expression, instead of a list comprehension, i.e. `(...)` instead of `[...]`:

```
gen = (x for x in itertools.product(*b) if len(x) == len(set(x)))
for x in gen:
    # do stuff
```

For 40 lists with 20 elements each, you get a whopping 10^52 combinations. The universe will likely die before you generate all of those. Assuming that *most* of those (almost all, in fact) would contain duplicates, you *could* try a more clever algorithm, skipping entire 'branches' of combinations as soon as you encounter the first duplicate, but I doubt that even those will help much.

Comment: It works fine but takes too long when the number of lists are more than 20.

Comment: More than 20? Have you calculated (on paper or with a calculator) how many combinations you expect? How big, exactly, is your data? E.g., for 3 items per list, those would be 3^20 i.e. 3,486,784,401 combinations... That _will_ take some time, no matter what approach you chose.

Comment: Max count of lists would be 40 & items in each list can go up to 20.

Comment: 40 lists with 20 elements, that would be 10^52 combinations. Good luck with that.

Answer (score 0):

Here are 3 ways to do this

```
a = [1,2,3],[1,4,5]
```

1. ```
   filter(lambda x: x[0] != x[1], [(x,y) for x in a[0] for y in a[1]])
   ```
2. ```
   combinations = list(itertools.product(*a))
   [value for value in combinations if value[0] != value[1]]
   ```
3. ```
   filter(lambda x:x[0] != x[1], combinations)
   ```

Answer (score -1):

Edit the second part of your code like such:

```
for  comb in combinations:
    if comb[0] == comb[1]:
        combinations.remove(comb)
```

Comment: its a bad idea to delete from a list while you are iterating over it